# debugging 3rd layer (secret q/a) of a php login page

Tags: php

I am building a page with 3 login layers as such. To login, user would need to enter the following details:

1. Account no and Password
2. Enter Pin Code (a 4 digit code)
3. Supply secret answer to a secret question the user entered at time of registration. eg 'What is your pet's name'?

How do I validate the secret question and answer in function.php, to allow a user login to his account section?

Right now, I can reach the point where the user is prompted for their username and password, and the pin is both accepted and validated, but when I get to the secret question and answer, secret.php is not accepting my answer.

It seems it is not validating the secret pin from the function.php file correctly

**function.php**:

```
<?php
require_once('mail.php');
/*
    Check if a session user id exist or not. If not set redirect
    to login page. If the user session id exist and there's found
    $_GET['logout'] in the query string logout the user    
*/

function checkUser()    
{
    // if the session id is not set, redirect to login page
    if (!isset($_SESSION['hlbank_user'])) {
        header('Location: ' . WEB_ROOT . 'login.php');
        exit;
    }

    // the user want to logout    
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        doLogout();
    }
}

    function next_tx_no() {
    $sql = "SELECT tx_no FROM tbl_transaction ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    extract(dbFetchAssoc($result));
    $tx_num     = (int)substr($tx_no, 2);
    $next_id    = $tx_num+1; // increment by One
    return 'TX'.$next_id;
}

function str_number($str) {
    $number = '';
    $number = str_replace('$', '', $str);
    $number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
    return doubleval($number);
}

function doPinValidation() {
    $errorMessage = '';
    $pin = $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp']['pin'];
    $ipPin = $_POST['accpin'];
    if($pin == $ipPin) {
        $_SESSION['hlbank_user'] = $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp'];
        unset($_SESSION['hlbank_tmp']);
        header('Location: secret.php');
        exit;
    }

    else {
        $errorMessage = 'Invalid pin numbers, please try again.';
    }
    return $errorMessage;
}

function doSecret() {
    $errorMessage = '';
    $secans = $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp']['secans'];
    $ipsecans = $_POST['accsecans'];
    $secque = $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp']['secque'];
    $ipsecque = $_POST['accsecque'];

    if($secans == $ipsecret) {
        $_SESSION['hlbank_user'] = $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp'];
        unset($_SESSION['hlbank_tmp']);
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }

    else {
        $errorMessage = 'Wrong Secret Answer, please try again.';
    }
    return $errorMessage;
}

function doLogin()
{
    $errorMessage = '';
    $accno  = (int)$_POST['accno'];
    $pwd    = $_POST['pass'];
    $pin    = $_POST['accpin'];


    $secque     = $_POST['accsecque'];


    $secans     = $_POST['accsecans'];

    $sql = "SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.email, u.is_active, u.pics, u.phone,
            a.acc_no, a.user_id, a.pin, a.type, a.status,
            se.secque, se.secans, se.user_id
            FROM tbl_users u, tbl_accounts a, tbl_secret se, tbl_address ad 
            WHERE a.acc_no = $accno AND u.pwd = PASSWORD('$pwd') 
            AND u.id = a.user_id AND se.user_id = u.id AND ad.user_id = u.id AND u.is_active != 'FALSE'";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);

    if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
        $row = dbFetchAssoc($result);
        $_SESSION['hlbank_tmp'] = $row;
        $_SESSION['hlbank_user_name'] = strtoupper( $row['fname'].'
 '.$row['lname']);
        header('Location: pin.php');
        exit;
    }

    else {
        $errorMessage = 'Wrong account number/password. Please try again.';
    }
    return $errorMessage;
}

/*
    Logout a user
*/

function doLogout()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['hlbank_user'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['hlbank_user']);
        //session_unregister('hlbank_user');
    }
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

function doRegister()
{
    $fname  = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname  = $_POST['lastname'];
    $pwd    = $_POST['password'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
    $dob    = $_POST['dob'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $add    = $_POST['address'];
    $city   = $_POST['city'];
    $state  = $_POST['state'];
    $zip    = (int)$_POST['zipcode'];
//  $accno  = (int)$_POST['accno'];
    $type   = $_POST['acctype'];
    $pin    = (int)$_POST['pin'];
    $secque     = $_POST['secque'];
    $secans     = $_POST['secans'];
    $errorMessage = '';
    $sql = "SELECT fname FROM tbl_users WHERE fname = '$fname'";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
        $errorMessage = 'Username already exist, please try another name.';
        return $errorMessage;
    }

    //first check if account number is already register or not...
    $accno = rand(9999999999, 99999999999);
    $accno = strlen($accno) != 10 ? substr($accno, 0, 10) : $accno;

    /*
    $sql = "SELECT acc_no FROM tbl_accounts WHERE acc_no = $accno";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
        $errorMessage = 'Account number is already register.';
        return $errorMessage;
    }
    */

    $images = uploadProductImage('pic', SRV_ROOT . 'images/thumbnails/');
    $thumbnail = $images['thumbnail'];
    $insert_id = 0; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, lname, pwd, email, phone, gender, 
is_active, utype, pics, bdate)
            VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', PASSWORD('$pwd'), '$email', '$phone',
 '$gender', 'FALSE', 'USER', '$thumbnail', NOW())"; 

    dbQuery($sql);
    $insert_id = dbInsertId();

    //now create a user address. 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_address (user_id, address, city, state, zipcode,

 country) 
            VALUES ($insert_id, '$add', '$city', '$state', $zip, 'USA')";


    dbQuery($sql);

    //and now create a account table entry...
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (user_id, acc_no, type, balance, pin, 

status, bdate) 
            VALUES ($insert_id, '$accno', '$type', 0, $pin, 'INACTIVE', NOW())";

    dbQuery($sql);

    //and now create a secret table entry...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_secret (user_id, secque, secans) 
            VALUES ($insert_id, '$secque', '$secans')";

    dbQuery($sql);

    //now send email
    //email it now. 
    $subject = "Account Registration";    
    $to = $email;
    $msg_body = "Dear Customer,<br/><br/>

    This is to inform you that your Account # $accno is register successfully with Elite Society Club and currently not active. We will contact you once it is activate.<br/><br/>In case you need any further clarification for the same, please do get in touch with us.<br/><br/>
    Regards,<br/>Elite Society Club";

    $mail_data = array('to' => $to, 'sub' => $subject, 'msg' => 'register', 
'body' => $msg_body);
    send_email($mail_data);
    header('Location: aregister.php');
    exit;
```

**secret.php**:

```
<?php
require_once './library/config.php';
require_once './library/functions.php';
$errorMessage = '&nbsp;';
if (isset($_POST['accsecret'])) {
    $result = doSecretValidation();
    if ($result != '') {
        $errorMessage = $result;
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<title><?php echo $site_title; ?></title>


<link href="<?php echo WEB_ROOT;?>css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" 

type="text/css">

<link href="<?php echo WEB_ROOT;?>css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" 

type="text/css">


<link href="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?

>library/spry/textfieldvalidation/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet"

 type="text/css" />


<script src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?

>library/spry/textfieldvalidation/SpryValidationTextField.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#ECECEC;margin-top:50px;">


<table width="750" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" 

class="graybox">

 <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF"> 


  <td><img src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>images/OnlineBanking-logo.png" /></td>


 </tr>

 <tr> 

  <td valign="top"> 

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">

    <tr> 

     <td class="contentArea">

        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 

id="acclogin">

      <h2 align="center"><strong>Login Step 3:</strong> Log in to Access your 

Account</h2>

      <p align="center">Enter Your Secret Answer to proceed </p>


      <div class="errorMessage" align="center"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?>
</div>

       <table width="350" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" 

cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#336699" class="entryTable">


        <tr id="entryTableHeader"> 


         <td><div align="center">:: Customer Login ::</div></td>


        </tr>


        <tr> 

         <td class="contentArea">


          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" 

class="text">

           <tr> 

            <td colspan="3"><div align="center"><?php echo $secque != "" ?


 $secque : "" ?>

              <p>&nbsp;</p>


            </div></td>


           </tr>


           <tr> 

            <td width="100" align="right">Secret Code</td>


            <td width="10" align="center">:</td>


            <td>


            <span id="spry_secans"> 


<input name="accsecret" type="text" id="accsecret" size="20" maxlength="30" />

              <br />

 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Secret Answer is required.</span>

<span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg">Secret Answer must specify at least 4 characters.</span>


<span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Secret Answer must specify at max 30 characters.</span>

            </span>

            </td>

           </tr>

           <tr> 

            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

            <td><input name="submitButton" type="submit"  id="submitButton" value="Validate Secret Answer" /></td>

           </tr>

          </table></td>


        </tr>

       </table>

       <p>&nbsp;</p>


      </form></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="contentArea" style="border-top:#999999 thin dashed;">


        </td>

    </tr>

   </table>


   </td>

 </tr>

</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

<!--

//

var spry_secans = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spry_secans", 'integer',

 {minChars:4, maxChars: 30, validateOn:["blur", "change"]});

//-->

</script>


</html>
```

Comment: you're not doing your security right ... there shouldn't be that many steps...

Comment: Kindly assist me to make correction pls . It will be really appreciated. Thank brother

Comment: Loopo, can you kindly send me  correction on my function.php file and the secret.php file.

Comment: removed most of the whitespace as there was so much the code was about three times too long. Also generally improved formatting and grammer where possible.